# how to create rules to send email notification for node reference content?

Tags: nodes, rules

I have two content types: job posting and job application.
The *job application* content type has a node reference field for *job posting*. Whenever  users create a *job posting* node, other users can send a *job application* to that *job posting* by filling the fields.

How can I send a notification to the user who had posted the *job application* node when the node has been created?

Answer (score 8):

Sure, with the [Rules module](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) create a new rule with this configuration:

1. At `admin/rules/trigger/add` choose a name for your rule
2. In the **Event** dropdown choose *After saving new content* and click 'Save changes'
3. Add a condition of: *Content has type* under the **Node** heading in the conditions dropdown
4. Add an action of: *Load a referenced node* under the **CCK** dropdown heading and choose the node reference field you want to use (the one in the job app content type) and click 'Save'
5. Add another action: *Load a user account* under the **User** dropdown heading. In the **User id** field, add `<?php print $referenced_node->uid; ?>` and click 'Save'
6. Add a third action: *Send a mail to a user* under the **System** dropdown heading, changed the **Recipient** dropdown to *Loaded user* and configure the Sender, Subject, and Body of the email and click save.

Now when a user creates a job application an email will be sent to the user who created the referenced job posting (assuming there is a value in the node reference field, it should be required).

Answer (score 1):

For D7

you can try something like this

Conditions:

Entity has field >>>> select your entityreference field

Actions:
Fetch entity by id >>>> node:your-reference-field:nid
(this should pull data from the node that is referenced via your entity reference field)

Now, if the email field is on your referenced node that should become available when you drill down

eg: node:your-reference-field:field-email