# How do I schedule a reminder email with Rules to users that have flagged an event?

Tags: rules

- I have a content type: `event`
- It has a single date field: `date`
- It has a flag on it: `reminder`

When the user flags the node, I want to schedule a rule to send them an email the day of the event.

Can someone walk me through the steps on how to do this?

Edit: I have now gotten as far as being able to schedule the email

This is what I have so far.

Add new component
 - Type: `Action set`
 - Name: `Send reminder email`
 - Data Type: `User`
 - Data Type: `Node`

Add action
 - Send reminder mail
 - To: 'user:mail'
 - Subject: `Don't forget about [node:title]`
 - Body: 
 - Don't forget about [node:title] tomorrow!

Create new Rule
 - Name: Schedule reminder email
 - React on Event: A node has been flagged, under "Remind"

Condition: Entity has field Data Selector flagged-node  Field: Date

Action: Schedule component evaluation Action set: Send reminder email

Comment: I "*think*" that anything starting from your "edit" is actually an answer to your question (I can't find anything wrong or missing in it). Therefor I think you should MOVE everything from that "Edit:" (to the end of your question) to an actual answer, so that you can also mark it as "accepted" later on (and so that this question no longer shows up in the list of unanswered questions). If you agree, and after you performed such move, please let me know via an extra comment here. BTW: the answer that you granted the bounty to has broken links ...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you know how to set up the Flag. Triggering a Rule with Flag is piece of cake and NodeOne has an create [15min tutorial](http://nodeone.se/en/learn-flag-with-nodeone-part-6-triggering-rules-with-flag) covering all the details. They also have all the [needed training on Rules](http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-rules-framework) if your fuzzy about Rules in general. Once your ready to set up your rule and you have the event to trigger it, you can set up the email action following a recipe similar to [this other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/how-to-create-rules-to-send-email-notification-for-node-reference-content). In your case you have the future event. Lullabot has a tutorial specifically on the [Rules Scheduler](http://drupalize.me/videos/introducing-rules-scheduler).

Comment: woohah! my first bounty! :D thanks and good luck with your project.

Comment: This answer has 2 broken links, can you fix them?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with this kind of rules setup is finding event when the action will take place. Rules scheduler has been talked on drupal.org & there are some bit of documentation at https://drupal.org/node/517674. It may help you.

There are other option to do it by help of your own module by implementing [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to fire e-mail on such condition which will be met by DB query condition given by you.

Comment: I would love to know the reason of negative vote..

Comment: You mention "Problem with this kind of rules setup is finding event when the action will take place.". As mentioned I have a flag on the node. This will trigger the event to schedule the action.

Comment: @NigelWaters - May be you have edited the question but when I answered, you wanted to set rules to send email on the day of the event to those user who has registered to any event. Anyway the thing which you are suppose to do is not hard as per my knowledge but I won't take chance answering again for negative vote..may be your requirement changes again...

Comment: I did not edit the question. You may have misread it. It always referenced flagging.

Comment: Where is the action on the day of event ?

Comment: @RajeevK : that downvote is not from me ... Possible reasons for the downvote: (1) What you perceive as a problem (find event) may not be perceived like so by somebody else (I also think that is not a problem, since I know which event to use) (2) the question is about "how to ...", not "where to find information to find out how ..." (3) the hyperlink to D.O. could at least have a link title, and even better you could have included a relevant "quote" here (4) about "There are other options ... hook_cron ...", I trust you know how to do so, but you don't say "how". Just trying to help, ok?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Or one more possible reason is "He was looking for someone else to complete his task". If you look into the revisions of this question, you would find it as altogether a different question. There was this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64695/how-do-i-use-rules-scheduler-to-disable-and-enable-a-commerce-product-entity-bas as question & which he later changed. And then voted my answer negative.. Anyway, doesn't matter anymore..

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Actually I could have even helped him in providing code for similar task as I was working on a complex Drupal Commerce project with many similar feature that time. I understood his issue in first instance & knew that Cron or Schedular can solve this. As you know, Rules set works on any trigger based on any user action (which he did do by having REMINDER flag). But instead of understanding the logic, he downvoted. Thanks for upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

You can add flag on your node called "reminder users" to send bulk emails. create rule on that flag so that rule will run once the flag update. in rules action. fetch users who flagged this node for attending this event. next create a loop to add users emails into your list and use send HTML e-mail into same loop to send email to all users who flagged this node.