# How to 'Entity Reference' using Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I am simply trying to autopopulate a Taxonomy Term from Content Type A into Content Type B.

An example, I'm creating a review site for Cars:

Content Type A = Car Model
field: field_car_model_tag

Content Type B = Car Review
field: field_car_review_tag

Assuming, Content Type A|CAR MODEL has already been created, titled "FORD MODEL".... My users will find and click a "Review Ford" link that routes them to Content Type B|CAR REVIEW, and auto-populates the Node Reference field (Node Reference URL Widget, for example, even though I'm attempting to only use Entity Reference fields).

After saving this same Content Type B|CAR REVIEW node, I would like this field, 'field_car_review_tag' to automatically populate with it's sister term from Content Type A|CAR MODEL.

In Drupal 6 Rules, I found this to be very straightforward.
I would simply "Load a referenced node, and then set a CCK field without validation", applying the token from the referenced content type.  In Drupal 7, the settings are seemingly endless.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've resolved this issue; least it looks good so far.  Super thanks to Alauddin's response to "[how to create rules to send email notification for node reference content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/how-to-create-rules-to-send-email-notification-for-node-reference-content/163492#163492)"

EVENT 
After saving new content of Car Review

CONDITION

- Entity has field
- data selector: node:field-car-review-node-reference
- value: field_car_model_tag

ACTION

- Fetch Entity by ID, with value: `node` and data selector: `node:field-car-review-node-reference:nid`
- Set a data value, with selected data (that I want to change): `node:field-car-review-node-reference:field-car-model-tag`

I think I have this right, here is an export of my Rule:

```
{ "rules_term_ref_4" : {
"LABEL" : "TERM REF 4",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : {
  "node_insert--car_review" : { "bundle" : "car_review" },
  "node_update--car_review" : { "bundle" : "car_review" }
},
"IF" : [
  { "entity_has_field" : {
      "entity" : [ "node:field-car-review-node-reference" ],
      "field" : "field_car_model_tag"
    }
  }
],
"DO" : [
  { "entity_fetch" : {
      "USING" : { "type" : "node", "id" : [ "node:field-car-review-node-reference:nid" ] },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "node:field-car-review-tag" ],
      "value" : [ "node:field-car-review-node-reference:field-car-model-tag" ]
    }
  }
]
}
}
```